# Pagination Not working in MSSQL+ PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pagination

I am trying to paginate my database blog posts in front end.

here is the code.

```
            <h2>Blogs</h2>
              <?php 
              $limite = 2;
              $pg = (isset($_GET['pg'])) ? (int)$_GET['pg'] : 1;
              $inicio = ($pg * $limite) - $limite;
              $lastRow = $inicio + $limite;
              $total = 0;

              include_once('includes/db-connect.php');
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Pk_blog_id) as row FROM dbo.tb_IEAG_Blogs) a WHERE row between ".$inicio." and ".$lastRow.""; 
              $a2 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
              $sqlcounter = "SELECT Pk_blog_id,Blog_title,Blog_content FROM dbo.tb_IEAG_Blogs WHERE Is_archived = 0 ";
              $acounter = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sqlcounter);

              while ($result1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($acounter)) {
                $totalintable++;
              }
            ?>

             <?php while($result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($a2)){ ?>
             <div class="media">
               <div class="media-body">
                 <h3 class="media-heading"><?php echo $result['Blog_title'];?></h3>
                 <p><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php echo date('F d, Y',strtotime($result['Created_at']));?></p>
                 <p><?php echo substr($result['Blog_content'], 0, 280) . '...'; ?></p>
               </div>
               <a class="btn rm-blg" href="blog-details.php?pkid=<?php echo $result['Pk_blog_id'];?>">Read More</a>
             </div>
             <?php } ?>  


          <?php $qtdPag = ceil($totalintable/$limite); 

            if($qtdPag > 1 && $pg <= $qtdPag)
            {
              ?>
            <nav class="text-center">
              <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" aria-label="Previous" class="next">
                    <span ><img src="images/prev.png" alt=""></span> Previous
                  </a>
                </li>
                <?php 
                for($i = 1; $i <= $qtdPag; $i++)
                {
                  if($i == $pg){
                    echo "<li><a class='ative'>".$i."</a></li>";
                  } else {
                    echo "<li><a href='blog.php?pg=$i'>".$i."</a></li>";
                  }
                }
                ?>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" aria-label="Next" class="prevs"> Next
                    <span ><img src="images/next.png" alt=""></span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>  
            <?php } ?>
```

I am getting pagination links but it is not correct.

I am limiting per page as  2 blog posts.

Total rows in Table is 6.

First page is working good and when going to second page its showing three records per page.

How can I solve this issue..

Thanks

Comment: does the last result of the first page appear as the first result on the second page?

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicion that the *last* record on the first page is appearing as the *first* record on the second page. This is all down to the way you have set up your record selection variables `$inicio` and `$lastRow`.

If we are you take your calculations we get the following results:

```
+------+-------+-------+-----+
| Page | Limit | Start | End |
+------+-------+-------+-----+
|    1 |     2 |     0 |   2 |
|    2 |     2 |     2 |   4 |
|    3 |     2 |     4 |   6 |
+------+-------+-------+-----+
```

*Start = `(page * limit) - limit`; End = `(page * limit)`*
*eg `Start = (1 * 2) - 2 = 0` `End = (1 * 2) = 2`*

The result being that you are getting 3 results in total for every page - the *Start* and *End* figures are inclusive (page 2 gives records: 2, 3, 4). The reason for the first page only having two records is because record number 0 doesn't exist as it starts from Row 1.

If you change your variables to something like this:

```
$inicio = (($pg - 1) * $limite) + 1;
$lastPage = ($pg * $limite);
```

You get the following results:

```
+------+-------+-------+-----+
| Page | Limit | Start | End |
+------+-------+-------+-----+
|    1 |     2 |     1 |   2 |
|    2 |     2 |     3 |   4 |
|    3 |     2 |     5 |   6 |
+------+-------+-------+-----+
```

*eg `Start = ((1 - 1) * 2) + 1 = 1` `End = (1 * 2) = 2`*